# Yii2 - Output of extra characters in generated email message

Tags: character-encoding, yii2, swiftmailer, url-encoding, activation

I am trying to send Account Activation Link via an email message to new users. I am using default mailer in Yii2. I generate following code to generate email body by using a view file, 'activation_request_email'.

```
$emailMessage = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('activation_request_email', ['userModel' => $this]);
```

Then in view file I use following code to generate Activation Link:

```
<?= Html::a ('Activation Link', ["site/activation", "key" => $userModel->email_activation_key])?>
```

Message is sent successfully, but generated email message including link in message always contains some extra characters like "3D" and "=". Like below:

```
<a href=3D"/tbpv2/web/site/acti=vation?key=3DfW_9XM-bdxXDHCTEwPTAPL1wwKGcc3">Activation Link</a>
```

Configurations for mailer component are:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => true,
    ],
```

Snippet of generated html header in message is as under:

```
<head> <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/ht=ml; charset=3DUTF-8" /> <title> Reset Token</title>= </head>
```

What can be the cause?

Comment: Using `useFileTransport = true  ` mean you are not sending send mails to real email addresses.

Comment: Are you sure the `href` part in your code is ok? It seems like `3D` before quotation should not be there, plus in the link - `acti=vation` seems weird.

Comment: @Joe Yes, "3D" and "=" characters are appearing arbitrarily through out the generated message.

Comment: Do you use `i18n`? What is your `urlManager` configuration?

Comment: @Joe urlManager config: 'showScriptName' => false, 'enablePrettyUrl' => true

Answer (score 0):

You have typo

```
 <?= Html::a ('Activation Link', ["site/activation", "key" => $userModel->email_activation_key])?>
```

try remove the space after a

```
<?= Html::a('Activation Link', ["site/activation", "key" => $userModel->email_activation_key])?>
```

Just for check if the problem is related to the helper funtion or other try echoing the html code this way

```
<?php echo "<a href='yuor_site..../site/activation?key=" .     
      $userModel->email_activation_key . "'>Activation link</a"; ?>
```

and test the result

then try this way

```
$activationLink = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/activation', 'key' => model->email_activation_key]);


<?= Html::a(Html::encode($activationLink), $activationLink) ?>
```

Comment: That does not seems to be a problem. However, no effect. Please see my updated question. Message is sent successfully, but generated email message including link in message always contains some extra characters like "3D" and "=".

Comment: Problem is specific to email output sent using Yii2 default mailer.

Comment: Then show mailer config ( yourApp/config/main.php o main-local.php )

Comment: Updated question with mailer config.

Comment: Please see that additional characters "3D" and "=" appear throughout the message. See updated question with the snippet of generated html header in the message.

Answer (score 0):

`=3D` is a replacement for `=` caused by the encoding *Quoted-printable*. That is absolutely valid. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) and this [github issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/issues/16)

Wikipedia:

> Quoted-Printable, or QP encoding, is an encoding using printable ASCII
>   characters (alphanumeric and the equals sign =) to transmit 8-bit data
>   over a 7-bit data path or, generally, over a medium which is not 8-bit
>   clean. It is defined as a MIME content transfer **encoding for use in**
>   **e-mail**.